# Why do we need prefix, postfix notation

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction, programming-languages, formal-languages

I know how each of them can be converted to one another but never really understood what their applications are. The usual infix operation is quite readable, but where does it fail which led to inception of prefix and postfix notation

Comment: sin(x) is prefix.  -x is prefix.  Prefix is used regularly along with infix.  What more do you need to know except "you're already using it".

Comment: @S.Lott: I believe he means for binary operators.

Comment: For postfix, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_Notation" "... parenthesis-free as long as operator arities are fixed."

Comment: It may be that infix is quite readable only because we are so accustomed to it!

Comment: I feel that prefix would be more intuitive had we been raised accustomed to it. Prefix is easy to program for in computers, but postfix uses less memory.  Infix is the worst in every way, both for humans (IMO) and computers

Comment: I suggest you to read about these notations for this link http://itviewson.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/infixprefixpostfix.pdf. It will clear your all confusions

Comment: Maybe its practically easy for the compilers?

Comment: @MooingDuck If evaluated from right-to-left prefix is same as postfix. If evaluated left-to-right prefix is faster than postfix because it supports short-circuit optimization for boolean operators.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Infix notation is easy to read for *humans*, whereas pre-/postfix notation is easier to parse for a machine. The big advantage in pre-/postfix notation is that there never arise any questions like operator precedence.

For example, consider the infix expression `1 # 2 $ 3`. Now, we don't know what those operators mean, so there are two possible corresponding postfix expressions: `1 2 # 3 $` and `1 2 3 $ #`. Without knowing the rules governing the use of these operators, the infix expression is essentially worthless.

Or, to put it in more general terms: it is possible to restore the original (parse) tree from a pre-/postfix expression without any additional knowledge, but the same isn't true for infix expressions.

Comment: Prefix and postfix notation still require one to know how many operands each operator takes. They can't be parsed without that knowledge. Lisp gets around this by parenthesizing each sub-expression. `1 2 # 3 $` could equivalent to `($ (# 1 2) 3)` or `($ 1 (# 2) 3)`.

Answer (score 6):

Postfix notation, also known as [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_Notation), is very easy to process left-to-right.  An operand is pushed onto a stack; an operator pops its operand(s) from the stack and pushes the result.  Little or no parsing is necessary.  It's used by Forth and by some calculators (HP calculators are noted for using RPN).

Prefix notation is nearly as easy to process; it's used in Lisp.

Comment: No, Lisp doesn't use prefix notation. In Lisp, everything is parenthesized.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter: Yes, everything is parenthesized, but the stuff between the parentheses uses prefix notation: `(+ 2 2)`.  It's not *pure* prefix notation.

Comment: 8 years later: The parentheses make it possible to specify how many arguments are passed to a function without knowing how many it expects.

Answer (score 2):

At least for the case of the prefix notation: The advantage of using a prefix operator is that syntactically, it reads as if the operator is a function call

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect of prefix/postfix vs. infix is that the arity of the operator (how many arguments it is applied to) no longer has to be limited to exactly 2. It can be more, or sometimes less (0 or 1 when defaults are implied naturally, like zero for addition/subtraction, one for multiplication/division).