# Display the generated equation

Tags: java, android, random

I'm working on a school project in Android Studio and I've already asked here how to randomly generate equations, like 10+48*4. Someone suggested me this code to generate the equations:

```
String[] operationSet = new String[]{"+", "-", "/", "*"};

public void testGenerateRandomEquations() {

Random random = new Random();
int numOfOperations = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

List<String> operations = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
    String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(3)];
    operations.add(operation);
}

int numOfNumbers = numOfOperations + 1;
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
    int number = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) - random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    numbers.add(number);
}
//Now you've the list of random numbers and operations. You can further randomize
//by randomly choosing the number and operation from those list.
}
```

But now I don't know how to display the generated equation. How can I display the equation for example in a TextView?
Maybe I'm just too dumb to understand but it would be nice if someone could help me :)

Here is the link to the original post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39960279/6949270

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to loop over the two lists - `numbers` and `operations` and concatenate them into a single string:

```
String equation = null;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperatrions; i++) {
    equation += numbers.get(i);
    equation += operations.get(i);
}
equation += numbers.get(numbers.size() -1);    //Add the last number to the equation
```

The last line is needed because there are more numbers (one more) than operations.
It is better to use `StringBuilder` than `String` when concatenating strings, but for short strings it's OK.
**EDIT** - Why does it work?
We are concatenating `String` with an `Integer`, using the `+` operator.
The JAVA compiler converts in this case the `Integer` into a `String`, so no other casting is required.

Comment: This won't work because the String has not been initialized. You should add `String equation = "";`

Comment: So now if I want to display the equation I just need to call up the string equation?

Comment: Yes. The `equation` string containg your text, so you can display it in a `TextView` with the `setText` method.

Comment: Thank you all lot!! What I've now done is I placed a button and if you press this it generates a random equation :D It works almost perfectly, the only thing I've noticed so far is that none of the equation contains multiplications but I hope I will figure out why and fix it.

Comment: The solution to the problem with the multiplication is the following:
In the code line:
`String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(3)];`
You just need to replace the "3" with a "4". :D

Comment: Is there a way to save the equation in a double? Because I need the equation in a double for a further step...

Comment: What do you mean? The "equation" is a `String` - just a bunch of characters. `Double` is something completly different. Do you mean "the result of the equation? If so, you'll have to solve it.

Comment: I need to have the equation in a double, float, int or long because I want to evaluate the result of the equation by using the "abs" command which unfortunately doesn't support strings. So is there a way to store the equation directly in a double, float, int or long? (I tried to convert the string to a double but then there are still the qoutation marks which a double can't contain) Or is there an other way to solve the equation?

Comment: A quick search gave me that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form. I'm sure there're more answers, just search.